# Pandas group by and filter by

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `data` and I have a `datetime` column called `created_at` and a column called `text`. I'd like to extract the rows whose `created_at` day matches an input day (from a given range), as well as the `text` value starting with the letter "a".

My dataframe is quite large so I thought that initially I'd group by the days and then use the grouped up dataframe to filter for each individual day and text.

```
data.set_index('created_at').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))
```

However, I am not sure how to apply the final filter. (I am also not sure if this is the best way to achieve what I wanted)

Comment: [groupby filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-filter) ? With the very minimal understanding of what your dataframe looks like and what you want to achieve it's hard to determine if this is the best way to achieve your goal.

Comment: @HenryEcker I want to obtain the entires whose `created_at` matches a day that I give it + the `text` column should also start with "a". The only issue is that the dataframe itself has a lot of rows and I want to do this operation for a lot of days.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the rest because you didn't give us a example of a shortend version but I can at least match the input with the column.

```
input = input("input datetime :  ")
created_at_column = df.loc[:, created_at] # df is your DataFrame
[x for x in list(created_at_column) if x == input]
```

Answer (score 0):

As @HenryEcker said, it's difficult to determine the best choice for you.
I generate 1836 dates between 2021-05-01 and 2021-05-31 and 1836 words from nltk (lower case)

```
# criteria
input_day = "2021-05-30"
first_letter = "a"

# Pandas to Numpy
created_at = data["created_at"].dt.date.values.astype("datetime64[D]")
text = data["text"].values.astype("<U1")  # keep only the first letter

# Filter
out = data.iloc[np.nonzero((created_at == np.datetime64(input_day))
                           & (text == first_letter))]
```

```
>>> out
                        created_at            text
1794 2021-05-30 07:54:46.103542234    alienability
1819 2021-05-30 17:43:19.455040872  anthologically
1820 2021-05-30 18:06:51.989100817     appreciativ
1830 2021-05-30 22:02:17.329700272     acoustician
1832 2021-05-30 22:49:22.397820163       afternote
```